# Unable to access Web API using AJAX from different machine when using HTTPS

Tags: ajax, ssl, internet-explorer, asp.net-web-api2

I have two machines as below:

**192.168.0.5**
On above machine Web API is hosted on port 10000 as below:
`https://192.168.0.5:10000/api/CFP/GetCustomerName`

On same machine an HTML page is hosted which is accessing the above API using AJAX
`https://myserver/htmlpage.htm`

Here `myserver` points to same IP which is `192.168.0.5`

I can access the above Web API using Postman and also HTML page on same machine. On HTML page I get a warning about SSL but it works. But from a different machine (given below), only Postman is able to access the Web API and not HTML page.

**192.168.0.6**
On this machine if I open Postman and try to access above Web API URL then it works. BUT I have to turn off `SSL certificate verification` in Postman settings otherwise it doesn't work.
On this same machine if I open that HTML page which in turn access that Web API then it doesn't work. I feel like it has something to do with SSL certificate.

Browser is IE 11 and I have disabled `Warn about certificate address mismatch` in `Advanced` setting of browser but no luck.

How do I fix this issue?

Comment: Does IE 11 show any error or warning message in the console? If you try to use any other browser, still the same issue persists?

Comment: *"... then it doesn't work. ..."* - what exactly does this mean? Can you please provide the specific error messages and a more detailed description of what you consider "working" and what you consider "not working"? Note there is nothing known about your application except that there is some static page on one port and some API on another port. Please check also with other browsers like Chrome which might give you more detailed information in the developer console.

Comment: I am displaying Javascript alert on screen and it just displays "undefined". There is no error in console. Unfortunately there is no other browser on machine. By the way directly typing Web API URL in browser on other machine works!
It just doesn't work from HTML page. Actually it's oversimplification as this is not HTML page but a SharePoint page.

Comment: If possible, please try to create an HTML page on that machine and try to install other web browsers then try to test the issue with all available browsers. It can help you to narrow down the issue of whether the issue is related to the IE 11 browser or not.